# Changing bot language in middle of the conversation

Tags: azure-devops, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am creating a bot service which can talk in any supportive language. My question is if the person started in English to chat and in middle he is not comfortable with English and want to change to Spanish or French. I would like to give that feature.

Is there any possibility to change the language of the bot in middle?
Any one faced the same issue helped is a great thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Composer for your bot?

Answer (score -1):

The logic wants to develop is appreciated, unfortunately such type of middle changes of languages in not yet supportive. Instead, create the bot, that will ask for language change if needed and take the response. If the response is ***`"YES"`*** then give the feasibility to the user to change the language. But the conversation up to that point happened cannot be converted. It is too complex to think.

For language supportive check: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/microsoft-teams-supported-languages-for-help-content-9c71d10a-0c5c-49d4-b6d7-0c58cdfdf4cf

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response @SaiamTadepalli-MT. I am looking for the immediate response. Even thought the required thing is not possible, can you give any kind of document support to change the bot conversation in middle to ask the repeated language change question to the user?